# How to get value from query using select as. It returns NULL instead of value

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have query:

```
$query = Task::query()->select(['tasks.*', 'rootTask.is_public as rootPublic']);
        $query->leftJoin('tasks as rootTask', function ($join) {
        $join->on('tasks._lft', '>=', 'rootTask._lft')
            ->whereNull('rootTask.deleted_at')
            ->where('tasks._lft', '<=', 'rootTask._rgt')
            ->whereNull('rootTask.parent_id');
        });
```

when I try to get $task->rootPublic it returns NULL
But if I do $query->toSql(); and run that SQL it returns 1.

What can be an issue?

Comment: rootPublic is in the fillable array?

Comment: @KhayamKhan why it should? In Laravel, the $fillable property within an Eloquent model is used to specify which model attributes are mass-assignable. This property helps to protect against mass assignment vulnerabilities, ensuring that only specified fields can be updated en masse through Eloquent's create or update methods.
It's virtual property at all

But I tried, nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

When you use select(['tasks.*', 'rootTask.is_public as rootPublic']), Laravel may not map the aliased column correctly.

To resolve this issue, you can use the DB::raw method to define the alias directly in the select statement. Here's an updated version of your query:

```
$query = Task::query()->select(['tasks.*', DB::raw('rootTask.is_public as rootPublic')]);
$query->leftJoin('tasks as rootTask', function ($join) {
    $join->on('tasks._lft', '>=', 'rootTask._lft')
        ->whereNull('rootTask.deleted_at')
        ->where('tasks._lft', '<=', 'rootTask._rgt')
        ->whereNull('rootTask.parent_id');
});

$tasks = $query->get();
```

I hope it can help you! Thanks

Comment: No, it was right.
Error was in condition 
->where('tasks._lft', '<=', 'rootTask._rgt')
TO
->where('tasks._lft', '<=', DB::raw('rootTask._rgt'))

But than you for your advise